Различное количество репутации в выпадающем меню и на странице репутации при отмене массового голосования
Кажется, с -430 на этом скриншоте что-то не так...


У меня там сейчас -150 отображается

@andreymal, у меня уже тоже...

На SO реализована eventual consistency, т. е. второстепенные данные обновляются не сразу.

@AlexanderPetrov, я думал, она заключается в том, что данные появляются не сразу, а не в том, что вместо верных данных временно появляется какой-то рандом?
